# Subsetting data but getting rows of NA where information should be

Tags: r

full_data = full_data[!(full_data$RIF == 1), ]

I want to subset my dataframe and return all rows where the RIF is not equal to 1. This statement returns a dataframe that has random NA rows where information previously existed and RIF was not 1. Could someone please explain to me why this issue is happening?

Comment: Use `full_data[full_data$RIF !=1 & !is.na(full_data$RIF), ]`

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. I actually want to keep the NA's in the RIF column. I only want to remove the ones I know definitely are equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be an issue with `NA` in the data.  One option is to make use of `is.na` to take care of those elements having `NA` to return FALSE or else it would be `NA` and this creates the `NA` row in the subset data

```
full_data[(full_data$RIF !=1 & !is.na(full_data$RIF))| is.na(full_data$RIF), ]
```